# "We can't do this any more than we can do that" - meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction

> It is generally the case that there is no "natural" connection between a linguistic form and its meaning. The connection is quite arbitrary. We can't just look at the Arabic word vJ^ and, from its shape, for example, determine that it has a natural and obvious meaning ***any more than we can*** with its English translation form *dog*.

It would be appreciated, if someone please analyse or throw a light on the bold part, so that I could get it better?

Excerpt From: George Yule. “The Study Of Language.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I don't know if I understood what is your problem, but I will try to shed a light on it for you.

The word **can** in this sentence refers to the subject **we** and the verb **determine**. But try not to focus on the words, but the meaning of the whole sentence: **any more than we can [determine] with its English translation form dog.**

Basically he is saying that as you can't just take a look at the english translation of the word vJ^ and determine that it has a natural and obvious meaning, you can't just take a look at the Arabic word vJ^ *itself* and determine the same thing (that it has a natural and obvious meaning).

Did that help you?

Answer (score 2):

> It is generally the case that there is no "natural" connection between a linguistic form and its meaning. The connection is quite arbitrary. We can't just look at the Arabic word vJ^ and, from its shape, for example, determine that it has a natural and obvious meaning any more than we can with its English translation form dog.

The following sentence is really an interesting one.

> We can't just look at the Arabic word vJ^ and, from its shape, for example, determine that it has a natural and obvious meaning **any more than** we can with its English translation form dog.

I will take only the later part for simplifying

> I can't determine *[that it has a natural and obvious meaning]* **any more than** *[we can (determine) with its English form "dog"]*

This sentence has the pattern like this - *I can't determine **X** any more than I can determine **Y***.

That boils down to - my determination of **X** is either equal to or less than my determination of **Y**, but not greater than.

Simply and most likely it means - I can determine **X** the same way I can determine **Y**.

**X** = *that it has a natural and obvious meaning*

**Y** = *we can (determine) with its English form "dog"*

So that sentence simply means that it's not true that we look at the Arabic word and from its shape can determine that it has a natural and obvious meaning. Like we can't determine just by looking at the English word "dog". That Arabic word is "dog" when translated to English.

Comment: Is this linear algebra? :)

Comment: @MARamezani Ha ha...u are right, I sounded it like that...I just equate it that way :-) that obviously I shouldn't encourage other to do.

Comment: This is a tough question to tackle. There must be some simple way to explain, but I can't think of one right now.

Answer (score 2):

> We can't just look at the Arabic word *vJ^* and, from its shape, for example, determine that it has a natural and obvious meaning any more than we can with its English translation form *dog*.

Here's my try:

> 1. I don't know Arabic. I'm looking at the combination of Arabic letters **vJ^**. Just looking, not doing anything else. I want to know whether this strange inscription has any meaning. What are my chances?
>
>    - The chances are 0%.
> 2. I don't know English. I'm looking at the combination of English letters **dog**. Just looking, not doing anything else. I want to know whether this strange inscription has any meaning. What are my chances?
>
>    - The chances are 0%.

So, I can't hope for **any more** chances of success in my action 1 than in my action 2.

I can't hope for **any more** chances with my action 1 than I **can** with my action 2.

I can't just go ahead with my action 1 and hope for its success **any more than I can with** action 2.